# Differences in currency number formatter

Tags: php, symfony

I have a local vagrant vm, which has identical php/mysql versions to live servers. Im trying to format decimal to currency with currency symbol.
My approach:

```
    $fmt = new \NumberFormatter('lt_LT', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    return $fmt->formatCurrency(1598, 'EUR');
```

Everything would be great, but in vagrant vm the result is 1,598.00 € and in live server: 1 598,00 €

Tried searching settings in php.ini, but with no luck. Why the results are different? (lt_LT is Lithuanian locale).

Answer (score 0):

Results are different because it's depend of your local which must be different between your vagrant vm and your live servers.

To handle easily the output money you can try to use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php